# Apache CXF and .NET WCF webservice interoperability

Tags: java, web-services, wcf, cxf, wcf-interoperability

I have a .NET WCF WSDL containing

```
<mssp:SslContextToken xmlns:mssp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy" sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
```

When trying to connect to the webservice with Apache CXF 2.7.12 it says

```
WARNING: No assertion builder for type {http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SslContextToken registered.
...
org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: No signature token
```

It seems CXF cannot handle this kind of Microsoft-specific token exchange. I was looking for other libraries, but it seems I cannot find one in Java. Maybe someone can offer a good solution to remedy this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems WCF is configured to use SSLNego (negotiateServerCredential=true) which is not supported by java libraries. Please publish your WCF config or the full WSDL to get mroe details.

Comment: We are now using .NET on client side because this configuration is not interoperable, as you mentioned.